# add two integers in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

So basically what i want is to add two numbers and make a sum or total of it.

here's my code:

```
if (isset($this->date_filed) && !empty($this->date_filed) && !empty($this->date_forwarded_to_cmt_contractor)) {
            $date_forwarded_to_cmt_contractor = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->date_forwarded_to_cmt_contractor);
            $date_filed = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->date_filed);
            $interval = $date_filed->diff($date_forwarded_to_cmt_contractor);
            $this->cst_to_cmt = $interval->format('%a' . ' ' . 'Days');

            if ($this->status == 'RECTI03') {
                $now = Carbon::now();
                $date_forwarded_to_cmt_contractor = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->date_forwarded_to_cmt_contractor);;
                $interval = $date_forwarded_to_cmt_contractor->diff($now);
                $this->cmt_to_current_date = $interval->format('%a' . ' ' . 'Days');

            }

            $this->date_filed_to_current_date = $this->cst_to_cmt + $this->cmt_to_current_date;

        }
```

here's the part where ive tried adding them.

```
$this->date_filed_to_current_date = $this->cst_to_cmt + $this->cmt_to_current_date;
```

but i get this error. why ? :/

> "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Comment: did you `dd()` your value to know if its really integer?

Comment: haven't tried that. i'll make a quick google search to know how to do it. anyways thanks man

Comment: what? just dd($yourvalue); then its gonna show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about with type casting to `integer`?

```
$this->date_filed_to_current_date = (int)$this->cst_to_cmt + (int)$this->cmt_to_current_date;
```

When you've numbers with comma or any other unwanted characters that is not a number e.g `,` or `-` on the string then you'll get a Notice **A non well formed numeric value encountered** So better is to cast it to integer type before add operation.

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/DAcWa

Comment: @allenconbulan glad it helps you some how. Best of luck :)